# What does @Configuration *really* mean in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I've been researching Spring Boot for a project, and I could use some help. The docs refer to `@Configuration` in kind of a vague way - it's a replacement for XML-based config. Other sources refer `@Configuration` as marking "a source for Bean definitions."

I'm relatively new to Java and struggling with some of the language, but my understanding so far is: `@Configuration` marks a class that contains methods that generate beans (which are really just classes getters/setters and at least a no-arg constructor). These methods should be annotated `@Bean`. This is important for Spring because this is how it manages IoC - it gathers methods that can create objects, and hunts around for `@Autowired` definitions (using reflection?). When it finds one, it executes the appropriate function that creates the object.

Is this accurate? I've spent a while thinking that `@ Configuration` was a way to set more trivial application state, but it sounds like it's actually a source of essential application structure (the classes).

Comment: Have you seen http://www.baeldung.com/inversion-control-and-dependency-injection-in-spring? I think you are on the right track.

Comment: I don't envy you trying to learn Java and Spring at the same time. I still have trouble wrapping my head around the 4-stacked exceptions with 80+ depth call stack with none of my own code in there.

Answer (score 6):

From Spring 4 official documentation [Annotation Type Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.0.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html)

It clearly states that a class having `@Configuration` annotation tells Spring container that there is one or more beans that needs to be dealt with on runtime. Depending upon your type of configuration i.e. Web or Non-Web, Spring bootstrap your `@Configuration` classes with the context.

Being said, you can do this configuration either via `xml` configuration file(s) or java based annotations (which is preferred, readable and easier).

You can read what else `@Configuration` annotated classes can do from the referenced documentation as well.